# Simple flood fill method causes StackOverFlow error

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow, flood-fill, minesweeper

My flood fill method:

```
public void fillNeighbours(int x, int y) {
    for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
            try {
                visible[x+i][y+j] = true;

                if(num[x+i][y+j] == 0) {
                    fillNeighbours(x+i, y+j);
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}
```

That `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {}` is there for avoiding x and/or y position from going outside of the array. Array size is 30 by 30. I'm making minesweeper like game. So you may know why I need this method and how it should work. If u don't know what minesweeper is then here is quick video about that game: [Introduction to minesweeper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7W6Wbv6zSQ)

Comment: You should almost never ignore/swallow exceptions like that.

Comment: 1. compute your bounds, don't use arrayIndexOutofBoundsExceptions! 2. From your code snippet, we cannot see anything that would terminate your loop. You keep invoking fillNeighbours. Check whether your num[x+i][y+j] is changed to something else than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code revisits fields which are set to visible already.

Try something like

```
if(!visible[x+i][y+j]){
  visible[x+i][y+j] = true;
  if(num[x+i][y+j] == 0) {
    fillNeighbours(x+i, y+j);
  }
}
```

Comment: That or `if(!visible[x+i][y+j])` the OP code seems to check one variable but set another. That said if the area to fill is large the stack could still overflow.

Comment: @Persixty the current data representation needs both checks. If the code would count neighbors on the fly then -1 (let's say) could encode visible=false, and 0...8 could represent visible=true.

Comment: You may be right. It's not exactly clear in the OP what the model is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're recursively calling `fillNeighbours` without any break out clause (base case) so the calls fill the stack.

From
 [Wikistack](http://wikistack.com/three-laws-recursion/)

The tree laws of recursion are

1. A recursive algorithm must have a base case.
2. A recursive algorithm
   must change its state and move toward the base case.
3. A recursive
   algorithm must call itself, recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Once fillNeighbours finds a cell and calls itself, the next loop will always call another when i and j are equal to zero.  So it will never exit, and crash once the stack is full.

Aside from that, it will produce a very deep tree as it is not keeping track of which cells have been recursed, and will call fillNeighbours on the same cell multiple times.